# Finding posts on which myself and another user participated

Tags: support, search

I would like to review posts that both myself and some nominated moderators have participated (asked / answered / commented) on. **How might I phrase the search?**

The obvious search for "user:123 and user:567" does not produce a list of this type. I have had limited success googling for our respective usernames, but I would prefer a solution that uses the SE search functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this SEDE query does more or less what you want: [Query for dotancohen](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/201664/query-for-dotancohen). Enter your user ID into one of the fields and enter the other user's ID into the other one. Here is an example using you and terdon over at U&L: [link](https://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/201664/query-for-dotancohen?User1=9760&User2=22222).

Disclaimer: I am god-awful at SQL, so this might be awful in any number of ways. Don't bother trying to run it on SO; it'll time out for sure, because this is inefficient as all sin.

Comment: Thank you senshin! This is quite what I have been trying to learn for the past half hour considering Werner's post.

Answer (score 2):

The (default) search results only return a single post. This implicitly limits a search result to *either* a question *or* an answer. So it is impossible to search for something that pertains to *two* posts (questions/answers). Moreover, comments are not searchable. The only way to achieve what you're after is to utilize the [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) and perform a query which combines the cases based on the post parent ID (or another ID).

For a see description of the field types (schema) available in the SEDE, see [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/168244).

Comment: Thank you Werner! This really is the my favorite answer, and I've been trying to formulate my SQL as per the SE schema. I selected senshin's answer as the correct answer as it did _answer the question_ but I stress that under most circumstances I prefer and encourage the push in the right direction, as you have done. Thank you!